# Emacs-Lisp lists, apostrophe ('), and backquote (grave accent, `)

Tags: list, emacs

I'm an emacs newbie and was going through this tutorial: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/elisp/

I wrote this code:

```
(defun hello (name)
  (insert (format "Hello %s!\n" name)))

(setq list-of-names '("John", "Jane", "Chad")) ;; -1-

(mapcar `hello list-of-names) ;;-2-
```

and when I did C-xC-e at line 2 the result came out as:

```
Hello John!
Hello (, Jane)!
Hello (, Chad)!
```

So I looked up what apostrophe does and it's a short hand for quote.

```
    (setq list-of-names (quote("John", "Jane", "Chad"))) ;; -1-
```

and results are the same. But when I accidentally replaced apostrophe with a grave accent(`, or SHIFT + ~ in my keyboard) it printed out correctly.

```
Hello John!
Hello Jane!
Hello Chad!
```

I've spent an hour looking up what grave accent does but no luck so far. Does anyone know what grave accent means in emacs?

I'm using emacs-w32 with Korean/English keyboard.

Comment: FYI: `M-x elisp-index-search RET \` RET` (one of the "self-documenting" aspects of Emacs). Type `C-h i h` to learn to use the Info reader -- doing so will pay huge dividends.

Comment: Your first misunderstanding, and the most important one, is how **list** elements are delimited in Lisp: use whitespace, not commas. The second is that backquote introduces a special context in which a comma has particular meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`` ` `` is similar to `'`, but when you can use `,` to prefix symbols that **won't** be quoted. See "Backquote" in the Elisp manual.

Lists in lisp aren't comma separated.

```
(setq list-of-names `("John" "Jane" "Chad" ,(current-time-string)))
(mapcar 'hello list-of-names)
```